# GD não funciona em arquivo criados em UTF-8

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como proceder em uma situação. Onde por padrão crio todos os arquivos do site com codificação padrão em UTF-8.

Mas quando tentei criar uma imagem com GD, a imagem aparece quebrada... Daí quando altero para Europero ocidental (iso-8859-1). Funciona corretamente.

Como faço funcionar este arquivo criado em UTF-8, para eu poder manter o padrão da criação dos arquivos?

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(200, 800)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 10, 5, 5,  "A Simple é você Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Suspeito que seja devido ao BOM. Quando usar utf-8 certifique-se de remover o caracter BOM (bit order mark)... Para fazer isso, usando o próprio editor de texto, configure o charset para "UTF-8 Without BOM". Isso depende do editor que utiliza.. Alguns definem como "UTF-8 ANSI".

Comment: Interessante isso, pois o DreanWeaver quando coloco sem BOM, ele não faz nada, continua gerando erro... Daí quando abro no notepad++ ele mostra o UTF-8 normal, acredito que seja problema no DreanWeaver, pois quando coloco sem Bom no  NotePad++ funciona corretamente...

Comment: @abcd Se puder adicione como resposta a resolução do problema, depois marque como aceita.

Comment: @DanielOmine coloca como resposta seu comentário p/ encerramos esta pergunta

Comment: está feito, Maison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando usar UTF-8 certifique-se de remover o caracter BOM (bit order mark).

Para fazer isso, usando o próprio editor de texto, configure o charset para "UTF-8 Without BOM".

Esse recurso depende do editor que utiliza. Alguns definem como "UTF-8 ANSI".

Note que essa resposta é baseada em uma suposição. 
Outros podem ter um problema similar cuja causa seja diferente da solução proposta.